# Replace Font Awesome with image on hover

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

I'm working with a template that uses Font Awesome for social media icons. Since one of the icons I need is not included in Font Awesome I found a CSS trick to overwrite a certain icon by a custom image. This works fine (fa-toggle-on can be replaced with any random icon):

```
.home i.fa.fa-toggle-on  {
content:url(\http://www.url.com/image1.png);
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

However, when hovering this image I need to show a different PNG (different color). Let's say "image2.png". I've been puzzling with this for an hour or so and can't seem to fix it. Commands like ".home i.fa.fa-toggle-on a:hover" don't seem to do the trick. Any ideas? Everything will be highly appreciated!

The CSS for the "normal" Social Media icons with Font Awesome is as follows:

```
/**
 * SOCIAL ICONS
 */
#social-icons { 
padding: 0; 
margin: 0; 
}
#social-icons li {
display: inline;
float: left;
margin-right: 1px;
line-height: 32px;
}
#social-icons li a {
display: inline-block;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
text-align: center;
margin: 20px 0 0 0;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
     -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
        transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
#social-icons li a:hover {
height: 80px;
margin-top: 0;
background: #fff;
}
#social-icons li a i:before {
position: relative;
top: 5px;
font-size: 18px;
color: #fff;
-webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
   -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease;
     -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
        transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
#social-icons li a:hover i:before { top: 25px; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this line in the CSS

```
#social-icons li a:hover i:before
```

You need

```
#social-icons li a:hover i.fa.fa-toggle-on  {
content:url(\http://www.url.com/image2.png);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Works perfectly, thanks a lot for making my day!